# Tikz markin is overleaying other rows/columns (beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer

I am trying to highlight the two rows of a table on a beamer presentation using `tikzmarkin`. However, the highlight for whatever reason is overlaying both the first column and both the rows above and below. I am unsure about how to fix this.

Below a minimal working example:

```
  \documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
    \usetheme[numbering=none]{metropolis}
    % \documentclass[aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}
    
    \usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{bbm}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{arydshln}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{mathrsfs}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{textpos}
    \usepackage{accents}
    \newcommand{\ubar}[1]{\underaccent{\bar}{#1}}
    \captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}% redefines the caption setup of the figures environment in the beamer class.
    
    % \definecolor{dukeblue}{RGB}{0,0,152}
    % \setbeamercolor*{upperfootline}{bg=white, fg=dukeblue}
    % \setbeamercolor*{lowerfootline}{bg=dukeblue, fg=white}
    % \setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=dukeblue} 
    \setbeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}[totalframenumber]%
    \newcommand{\insertmyfootertext}{Boutros, Clara and Gomes (2022)}  %<--- Add text for left half of lower footer here
    %\newcommand{\insertmyimage}{master_fig/duke.png} %<--- Add image for right half of lower footer here
    \makeatletter
    \defbeamertemplate*{footline}{mycustomtheme}
    {%
      \leavevmode%
      \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=3.00ex,dp=1ex]{upperfootline}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}\insertshortauthor
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=3.00ex,dp=1ex,right]{upperfootline}%
        \usebeamertemplate{page number in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex} 
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
        \hbox{%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=3.00ex,dp=1ex]{lowerfootline}%
        \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\hspace*{2em}\vspace*{0.12em}\insertmyfootertext
      \end{beamercolorbox}%
      \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=3.00ex,dp=1ex,right]{lowerfootline}%
      %\includegraphics[width=1.2cm, height=4.1ex, keepaspectratio]{\insertmyimage}\hspace*{2ex}
      \end{beamercolorbox}}%
      \vskip0pt%
    }
    \makeatother
    
    \setbeamercolor{block body alerted}{bg=alerted text.fg!10}
    \setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{bg=alerted text.fg!20}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=structure!10}
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=structure!20}
    \setbeamercolor{block body example}{bg=green!10}
    \setbeamercolor{block title example}{bg=green!20}
    \newcommand{\credit}[1]{\par\hfill \footnotesize ~\itshape#1}
    
    \usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
    
    \tikzset{hl/.style={
        set fill color=red!80!black!40,
        set border color=red!80!black,
      },
    }
    
    
    %
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %   TITLE PAGE
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    \title[]{Title here}
    \author[]{Someone}
    \date{} 
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
    \end{frame}
    
    \begin{frame}{Title here}
    \tiny
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
    \begin{tabular}{lcccclcccclcccc}
    
\hline
                              & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Panel A: title A} & \textbf{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Panel B: title B} &           & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Panel C: title C} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & 26-30  & 31-35  & 36-40  & 41-65  & \textbf{} & 26-30   & 31-35  & 36-40  & 41-65  & \textbf{} & 26-30   & 31-35   & 36-40   & 41-65   \\ \cline{2-5} \cline{7-10} \cline{12-15} 
Dummy row 1    \tikzmarkin<2->[hl]{a}  & 0.431   & 0.654  & 0.693  & 0.316  &  & 0.462   & 0.236  & 0.136  & 0.240  &  & 0.107   & 0.109   & 0.171   & 0.444   \\
Dummy row 2 & 0.431   & 0.654  & 0.372  & 0.020  &  & 0.462   & 0.236  & 0.073  & 0.015  &  & 0.107   & 0.109   & 0.092   & 0.027   \tikzmarkend{a} \\ 
Dummy row 3                                  & 75.476  & 96.288 & 92.928 & 80.958 &  & 44.441  & 46.990 & 42.068 & 41.270 &  & 17.395  & 19.522  & 20.966  & 20.890  \\
Dummy row 4                           & 0.134   & 0.080  & 0.049  & 0.063  &  & 0.118   & 0.030  & 0.011  & -0.008 &  & -0.313  & -0.063  & 0.005   & 0.005   \\
Dummy row 5                             & 44.742  & 55.824 & 52.775 & 43.955 &  & 25.275  & 26.508 & 23.770 & 24.015 &  & 13.874  & 14.010  & 14.408  & 14.102  \\
Dummy row 6                      & 0.123   & 0.077  & 0.049  & 0.068  &  & 0.056   & 0.016  & 0.004  & -0.005 &  & -0.172  & -0.028  & 0.009   & 0.005   \\
Dummy row 7                    & 25.285  & 14.298 & 6.868  & 17.027 &  & 27.805  & 21.951 & 19.996 & 32.147 &  & 29.311  & 30.583  & 34.365  & 44.288  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is because the graphics are defined at the point when tikzmarkin is used, by which time the first row and column are already on the page so the picture goes on top.  One option would be to reduce the height and left padding of the box.  Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Yes - absolutely. Could you help me with doing that?

Comment: p.3 of the doc hf-tikz, we can write
\tikzmarkin<2->[hl,above left offset={0.2,0.2},below right offset={0.2,-0.1}]{a}